# Can we remove action from the Case Milestone layout?

Tags: casemilestone, entitlements

I am working on the `Entitlement Processes` and `Milestones`. Can we remove action (highlighted in red below screen shot) from the Case Milestones related list ?

Is there any setting by which we can do that ?

I have some questions around the OOTB SLA implementation:-

- Can we stop the SLA ? If yes then how ?
- As per my understanding, we can't add the Custom Fields in the CaseMilestone. Is this true ?
- Whats the difference between "Actual elapse time" and "Elapse Time" ?
- Can we add more than 10 fields somehow in the below screen shot ?

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Can we remove action (highlighted in red below screen shot) from the Case Milestones related list ?
>
> Is there any setting by which we can do that ?

If an user has Read permission to Case then he/she will have Edit to CaseMilestone object.

There are not separate sharing settings on CaseMilestone object. It is built-in.

> Can we stop the SLA ? If yes then how ?

Yes, we can stop SLA, use `IsStopped` attribute of Case Object,
`objCase.IsStopped = true`

> As per my understanding, we can't add the Custom Fields in the CaseMilestone. Is this true ?

So far, I know we can't add custom fields.

> Whats the difference between "Actual elapse time" and "Elapse Time" ?

`Actual elapse time` has not been exposed as API in CaseMilestone object.

I think Actual elapse time as also consider Stop timings in the calculation

> Can we add more than 10 fields somehow in the below screen shot ?

I think Salesforce only allows max 10 fields to be shown in any related list.

Comment: Let's say, you are waiting for client then based on the case status, you can stop the milestone. Check if that can be done through Workflow field update or process builder